# Get the last item from node list without using .length

Tags: javascript

The following code

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#divConfirm table')[1].querySelectorAll('tr')
```

returns a NodeList with 3 table row (`tr`) elements in it. If I know the list size, I can access the last element via NodeList's `.item(2)` method.

Is there a way to get the last element directly without resorting to `.length`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's at least one way

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('#divConfirm table')[1].querySelectorAll('tr');

var last = [].slice.call(els).pop();
```

but, the following statement

> But if I do not know the length prior to running the script

makes no sense, you already have the collection of elements, so you would always know the length

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('#divConfirm table')[1].querySelectorAll('tr');

var last = els[els.length - 1];
```

Another option as [the8472's answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231489/get-the-last-item-from-node-list-without-using-length/35231536#35231536) would be

```
document.querySelector('#divConfirm table:nth-child(2) tr:last-child');
```

Comment: This answer could benefit from explanations of what slice and pop do, and links to their definitions somewhere. If someone is not familiar with pop, for example, they might be very surprised to find out their array is now missing the element they popped.

Answer (score 8):

Since *NodeList doesn't have a pop method*.

Using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in a new array, then `pop()` to get the last element.

This basically copy the Nodelist as a regular array, thus the `pop()` and other array methods become available.

```js
console.log(
  // Last elem with pop()
  [...document.querySelectorAll("div")].pop()
)

console.log(
  //  2nd elem
  [...document.querySelectorAll("div")].slice(1)[0]
)

console.log(
  // By index :) just in case
  document.querySelectorAll("div")[0]
)
```

```html
<div>The sun</div>
<div>is</div>
<div>shinning</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

depending on circumstances this may work: `document.querySelector('#divConfirm table tr:last-of-type')`

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the `NodeList` into an Array. Then can use [array.pop()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pop.asp). It return the last item BUT remove it to the array!

```
const elementsArray = Array.from(elements);
elementsArray.pop()
```

Comment: This is of course ok, and since es6, the shorthand for `Array.from(e)` is the spread syntax `[...e]`